# Sidebar and tabbed info windows using google maps v2

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Does anyone know of an example where a Google Map is used to create a map with both a sidebar

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map4c.htm

and tabbed info windows

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map10a.htm?

The markers are defined and ready for sidebar

```
      function createMarker(point,name,html) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point,{icon:myIcon});

        // add a line to the side_bar html
        side_bar_html += '<div id="'+linkid+'"><a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br><\/div>';
        return marker;
      }
```

The sidebar gets its titles from the 'name' defined for the marker :

```
var marker = createMarker(point,"Point Title", 'Point Content')
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Tabs are generated by passing the markers into arrays :

```
      function createTabbedMarker(point,htmls,labels) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
```

and

```
   var marker = createTabbedMarker(point, ["Tab 1 contents", "Tab 2 contents","Tab 3 contents","Tab 4 contents"],["One","Two","Three","Four"]);
      map.addOverlay(marker);
```

My question is how can I grab just the first part of the array [labels], in this example 'One', and have that be what the output is for the sidebar ?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @zac; Made an attempt at solving the problem, let me know if it helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar in the first example is not a feature of the Google Maps API; i's just a table cell which is updated in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, sorry... that was a really unclear question.  I elaborated on it so it hopefully makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable ... if you check the Google Maps documentation on [`Gmarker`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker), or more specifically [`Gmarker.openInfoWindowTabsHtml`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.openInfoWindowTabsHtml), you will see that it takes two arguments:

1. An array of [`GInfoWindowTab`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowTab)'s
2. A [`GInfoWindowOptions`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions) javascript object.

In the documentation for [`GInfoWindowOptions`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions) you will see that you can pass in the tab index via the `selectedTab` property.  In that case, we can use the code from the [sidebar example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map4c.htm) and simply update the `myclick` function:

```
function myclick(i) {
        gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);
      }
```

becomes:

```
function myclick(i, tab_index) {
        gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i], { selectedTab : tab_index });
      }
```

And we update the `createMarker` function to accept the number of tabs this marker should have:

```
createMarker(point,name,html,tab_count) {
    // ...snip ...
    var links_html_temp = "";
    while (--tab_count) {
         links_html_temp = '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ',' + tab_count + ')">' + name + ': Tab #' + tab_count + '<\/a><br>' + links_html_temp;
    }
    side_bar_html += links_html_temp;
```

I'll leave it to your own specific implementation to pass the appropriate tab count to `createMarker`.